# Using prototype beans defined in a different java-based Spring config file

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

Assume we have two spring config files: `ConfigA.java` and `ConfigB.java`.

Here's how `ConfigA.java` may look like:

```
@Configuration
class ConfigA {

  @Scope("prototype") 
  @Bean public Foo fooPrototype() {
      return new Foo(params);
  }
}
```

And now I want to inject a few instances of `Foo` to a number of singleton-scoped beans declared in `ConfigB.java`:

```
@Configuration
@Import(ConfigA.class)
class ConfigB {

  @Bean public Bar bar() {
      return new Bar(*** how to inject Foo instance here? ***);
  }

  @Bean public Buzz buzz() {
      return new Buzz(*** how to inject Foo instance here? ***);
  }    
}
```

If I had a single configuration file, I would simply replace the blocks enclosed in asterisks  with `fooPrototype()`.

But, how to inject different Foo instances to bar() and buzz() beans provided `fooPrototype()` is declared in a different configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks similar to the example in the Spring documentation [§5.12.5 Composing Java-based configurations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-composing-configuration-classes).

This same page gives a solution: You can *autowire* the configuration beans.

```
@Configuration
@Import(ConfigA.class)
class ConfigB {

    @Autowired ConfigA configA;

    @Bean public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar(configA.fooPrototype());
    }

    @Bean public Buzz buzz() {
        return new Buzz(configA.fooPrototype());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just pass `fooPrototype` as a method arg? E.g.:

```
@Bean public Bar bar(Foo fooPrototype) {
    return new Bar(fooPrototype);
}

@Bean public Buzz buzz(Foo fooPrototype) {
    return new Buzz(fooPrototype);
}
```